# Aurelia Webpack: Source map shows error when this is not an error

Tags: webpack, aurelia

I am running into a problem where when I check my chrome dev tools, my js file claims that it has a syntax error on the first line, but everything on the browser appears to be running correctly.

[image]

Am I configuring something wrong on my webpack config files?

```js
// webpack.common.js

const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const { ProvidePlugin, DefinePlugin } = require('webpack');
const { AureliaPlugin, ModuleDependenciesPlugin } = require('aurelia-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const bootstrapEntryPoints = require('./webpack.bootstrap.config');

const nodeModulesDir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');
const bootstrapConfig = bootstrapEntryPoints.dev;
const production = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : false;
const cssRules = [
  { loader: 'css-loader', options: { minimize: production } }
];

console.log(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'));
module.exports = ({ coverage } = {}) => ({
 resolve: {
  extensions: [".js"],
  modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules'],
 },
 entry: {
     app: ['aurelia-bootstrapper'],
     vendor: ['bluebird'],
     bootstrap: [bootstrapConfig],
     font_awesome: 'font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss'
   },
 output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  // https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/webpack-the-confusing-parts-58712f8fcad9
  publicPath: production ? 'http://test.webpack.dev.web/' : '/',
  filename: production ? '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.js' : '[name].[hash].bundle.js',
  sourceMapFilename: production ? '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.map' : '[name].[hash].bundle.map',
  chunkFilename: production ? '[name].[chunkhash].chunk.js' : '[name].[hash].chunk.js'
 },
 module: {
    rules: [

   // CSS required in JS/TS files should use the style-loader that auto-injects it into the website
   // only when the issuer is a .js/.ts file, so the loaders are not applied inside html templates
   {
    test: /\.css$/i,
    //exclude: /node_modules/,
    issuer: [{ not: [{ test: /\.html$/i }] }],
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
     fallback: 'style-loader',
     use: cssRules
    })
   },
   {
    test: /\.css$/i,
    issuer: [{ test: /\.html$/i }],
    // CSS required in templates cannot be extracted safely
    // because Aurelia would try to require it again in runtime
    use: cssRules
   },
   {
             test: /\.scss$/,
             use: [
              // creates style nodes from JS strings
              { loader: "style-loader"}, 
              { loader: "css-loader"}, // translates CSS into CommonJS
              { loader: "sass-loader"} // compiles Sass to CSS
             ]
         },
   { test: /\.html$/i, loader: 'html-loader'},
   { test: /\.js$/i, loader: 'babel-loader' },
   // Use this for unit testing only
   // { test: /\.js$/i, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: nodeModulesDir,
   //   options: coverage ? { sourceMap: 'inline', plugins: [ 'istanbul' ] } : {},
   // },
   { test: /\.json$/i, loader: 'json-loader'},
   // // use Bluebird as the global Promise implementation:
   //{ test: /[\/\\]node_modules[\/\\]bluebird[\/\\].+\.js$/, loader: 'expose-loader?Promise'},
   // // embed small images and fonts as Data Urls and larger ones as files:
   { 
    test: /\.(png|gif|jpg|cur)$/i,
    loader: 'url-loader'
   },
   { test: /\.woff2(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/i, loader: 'url-loader'},
   { test: /\.woff(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/i, loader: 'url-loader'},
   // load these fonts normally, as files:
   { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|otf)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/i, loader: 'file-loader'},
   //To resolve datatable jquery issues:
   //{ test: require.resolve("datatables.net"),  use: "imports-loader?this=>window" },
   //To resolve bootstrap to run properly
   //{ test:/bootstrap-sass[\/\\]assets[\/\\]javascripts[\/\\]/, use: 'imports-loader?jQuery=jquery' },
   // To resolve font-awesome
   // https://medium.com/@estherfalayi/setting-up-webpack-for-bootstrap-4-and-font-awesome-eb276e04aaeb
   {
    test: /font-awesome\.config\.js/,
    use: [
     { loader: 'style-loader'},
     { loader: 'font-awesome-loader'}
    ]
   }
    ]
 },
 plugins: [
  new ExtractTextPlugin({
   filename: production ? '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.css' : '[name].[hash].bundle.css',
   allChunks: true,
  }),
  new AureliaPlugin({}),
  new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
  // new ModuleDependenciesPlugin({
  //       'aurelia-testing': [ './compile-spy', './view-spy' ],
  //    }),
  new ProvidePlugin({
   'Promise': 'bluebird',
   $: "jquery",
   jQuery: "jquery",
   'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
   'window.$': 'jquery'
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
   // change
   template: 'index.ejs',
   inject: true,
   metadata: { title: ''},
   favicon: "favicon.ico"
  }),
  // new CopyWebpackPlugin([
  //       { from: './src/favicon.ico', to: '/favicon.ico/' }
  //    ])
 ],
 // to resolve fs problem from numbro module
 // node: {
 //  fs: "empty"
 // }
});


/*

NOTES

current version: 2.0.0-rc.4

We released aurelia-webpack-plugin@3.0.0-rc.1 which is compatible with (and requires) Webpack 4. The major version bump is to prevent an automatic upgrade from 2.0.0-rc.5, which you should continue to use if you're still on Webpack 3.


https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16839

numbro: v2 is not using setLanguage instead of culture function

$ error with data tables usually means that script contains dtnet(window, $) <-- remove that bit of code and it will be fixed

Need to remove all dtnet function calls to jquery, webpack handles jquery

Set PLATFORM.moduleName function to routes and any config file that aurelia is trying to read


To migrate with webpack 4 : https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-4-migration-guide-for-plugins-loaders-20a79b927202

Update all ai-dialog to ux-dialog (for newer aurelia-dialog support)


https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-bits-learn-and-debug-webpack-with-chrome-dev-tools-da1c5b19554
Another way to enhance monitoring of webpack code

remove pre attribute from .message

*/
```

```js
// webpack.dev.js

const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

// https://webpack.js.org/guides/build-performance/
module.exports = merge(common({coverage:false}), {
 devServer: {
  port: 8555,
  contentBase: './dist',
  historyApiFallback: {
   index: '/',
   rewrites: [
    { from: '/favicon.ico/', to: '[favicon.ico]' }
   ]
  },
  stats: { colors: true },
  hot: true
 },
 // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#devtool
 //devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map', // Use for better speed development and hot reloads
 devtool: 'inline-source-map',   // Use if you want to see the original source on chrome dev tools
 plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
         'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('dev')
     }),
     new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
     // This will provide you with a heat map that shows what is taking up the most space for a given bundle
     //new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
     // placing here because karma breaks on commonsChunkPlugin with webpackjsonp not defined error
  // new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ 
  //  name: ['app', 'vendor', 'bootstrap', 'font_awesome'],
  //  minChunks: 3
  // })
  // new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  //        name: 'node-static',
  //        minChunks(module, count) {
  //            var context = module.context;
  //            return context && context.indexOf('node_modules') >= 0;
  //        },
  //    })
 ]
});
```

If resolved, this will something that will not be as distracting when debugging, thank you.

Comment: the image link is labeled as "enter image description here" on the original question. Don't know how to edit post.

Comment: this is my babelrc file: https://codeshare.io/GLZpwK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this is a chrome dev tool parsing problem as of Version 64.0.3282.186.

Checking google canary, I am no longer seeing this issue. This can be closed, unless someone else is experiencing a different problem.

Comment: You could mark your own answer as the answer, that will "close" it :)